# I need to have files named with different numbers attached to the end of them

Tags: bash

Here's the relevant portion of the shell script I am trying to write. I cannot figure out how to get the input variable to have varied numbering attached onto the end of it. This needs to happen so that the files are named differently and the script can continue to run. Being that -w is the file naming flag, this is the only one I need edited. Please help.

I need the file name to take what the user entered, and then add on numbers so that the file names are different from each other. Here's what I have so far:

```
echo "Enter filename or enter 'default' to use default file naming "
    read input_variable5
    if [  $input_variable5 "default" ]
    then
    nohup sudo tcpdump -i $input_variable1 $input_variable2 -G $input_variable3 -W $input_variable4 -w capture_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.pcap -z gzip </dev/null >nohup.out 2>&1 &
    else
    nohup sudo tcpdump -i $input_variable1 $input_variable2 -G $input_variable3 -W $input_variable4 -w mktemp "$input_variable5".XXXX.pcap -z gzip </dev/null >nohup.out 2>&1 &
    fi
```

Comment: You should write your variables like `${input_variable}`, that way you can add numbers to the end of them like `${input_variable}5 ${input_variable}4`.

Comment: OP, you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37493942/edit) your questions rather than delete them. When you delete, any information, comments and answers are lost.

Comment: Then people will not see the question and it goes unanswered anyway

Comment: @Matt Nope, when you edit - like you just did now - the question is pushed to the top again.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm extremely new to this so I didn't know that.

Comment: BTW, consider running code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds before asking questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use `mktemp`, you cannot append an extension to the end as the *TEMPLATE must contain at least 3 consecutive 'X's in last component* (see: *man 1 mktemp*).

If I understand your question, the simple solution is to implement a simple counter `$count` that checks to see whether a file name with the form `"$input_variable5.$count.pcap"` already exists, and if so, increment `count` by `1` until an unused name is found. You could do that with something like the following:

```
declare -i count=0

echo "Enter filename or enter 'default' to use default file naming "
read input_variable5
if [  $input_variable5 "default" ]
then
    nohup sudo tcpdump -i $input_variable1 \
    $input_variable2 \
    -G $input_variable3 \
    -W $input_variable4 \
    -w capture_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.pcap \
    -z gzip </dev/null >nohup.out 2>&1 &
else
    ## find first available unused filename for -w
    while [ -f "$input_variable5.$count.pcap" ]; do
        ((count++))
    done
    nohup sudo tcpdump -i $input_variable1 \
    $input_variable2 \
    -G $input_variable3 \
    -W $input_variable4 \
    -w "$input_variable5.$count.pcap" \
    -z gzip </dev/null >nohup.out 2>&1 &
fi
```

**note:** if you want to preserve the `XXX` (3-digit format, e.g. `000`, `001`, etc...), you can use `printf -v` to accomplish the increment. For example:

```
declare -i count=0
input_variable5=${1:-tmp}

printf -v fname "%s.%03d.pcap" "$input_variable5" "$count"

while [ -f "$fname" ]; do
    ((count++))
    printf -v fname "%s.%03d.pcap" "$input_variable5" "$count"
done
```

That would provide the `$input_variable5.$count.pcap` format where `count` is displayed as a `0`-padded 3-digit number.

If I haven't understood what you are attempting, let me know, otherwise, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks! That was it

Comment: Glad I could help. There is usually more than one way to *skin-the-cat* in bash.

Comment: @Matt: Don't forget to "accept" the answer that best helps solve your problem. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160242 . After  you have 10? reputation points, you can also up-vote answers (separately from accepting them). Reputation points are what keeps people here on S.O. answering Qs. Glad you got a solution here. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you're trying to set the variable `input_variable` when reading instead of `input_variable5` I think you're looking to do the following:

```
echo -n "Enter filename or enter 'default' to use default file naming: "
read input_variable
if [ "$input_variable" == "default" ]; then
    nohup sudo tcpdump -i ${input_variable}1 ${input_variable}2 -G ${input_variable}3 -W ${input_variable}4 -w capture_$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S').pcap -z gzip </dev/null >nohup.out 2>&1 &
else
    nohup sudo tcpdump -i ${input_variable}1 ${input_variable}2 -G ${input_variable}3 -W ${input_variable}4 -w mktemp "${input_variable}5".XXXX.pcap -z gzip </dev/null >nohup.out 2>&1 &
fi
```

This does mean that if you type in "default", then your else statement will have files `default1 default2` for your `-i` operator, and then for your `-G` will be `default3`, but eventually your `-w` will be `capture_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.pcap`.

Comment: I think what OP is not telling us, is that `$input_variable1`, `$input_variable2` etc. are set elsewhere in the code. `$input_variable1` is the `-i` parameter (the interface to listen on), `$input_variable2` is the `-G` parameter (the number of seconds between log rotations) and so on. If I understand it correctly, OP is simply after a unique file name in case none was provided by the user.

Comment: What this does for me is makes a file called mktemp and then ignores the rest of the code.

Comment: Yes exactly, the input variables are named like that, the only number I want changed is the one with the file name, so the -w input that the user is prompted to enter.

Comment: FYI, the only valid string comparison operator for POSIX test is `=`; `==` is an extension, and not available everywhere. See the relevant standard at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: (similarly, `echo -n` is not required by POSIX to be supported. Unlike `echo -e` [given which a POSIX-compliant implementation must print `-e` on output], it's *allowed* to be supported without making an implementation noncompliant, but it's better/safer to use `printf`, which is guaranteed; see the APPLICATION USAGE section of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html).

Comment: (...this is one of the few places where bash even in POSIX mode acts in a manner directly contrary to the specification, but if the `xpg_echo` option is enabled it'll behave in accordance, breaking code built with the expectation of a noncompliant `echo`).